# In php, is there a way to populate a functions arguements from a list of strings?

Tags: php

For example, if I have an array:

```
$indicators = ['open','high','low','close'];
```

Is it possible use these a function parameters without hardcoding them into the function?

```
customFunction($open,$high,$low,$close);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [spread syntax operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array) i.e.

```php
customFunction(...$indicators);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the spread operator, you could also use [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```php
call_user_func_array('customFunction', $indicators);
```